# how to achieve Role based authorization in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i stuck with Role based authorization in mvc3 i search lot in internet but did not find useful doc so please help me.. and please help me to create role in Asp.net membership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net SQL Server Setup

1. Go to location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

[image]

2. Dbl Click aspnet_regsql.exe

[image]

3. From set up Option , Select first optn : Configure SQL Svr for appln services 
   [image]
   ( Second option is used for removing services…)
   [image]
4. Now select DB  which you want setup

[image]

5. And Finish, your sql server is setup successfully for asp.Net.
   [image]
6. One more thing in web. Config... add this conection string.

   ```
     <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="<<Your DB Conection String goes here>>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```

……………………………………………….Enjoy ..Chears.